[heroku][sentry] Problem getting email notification from sentry
I am using Heroku dyno and added sentry as an add-on to my app. I have set an email in the settings of sentry and verified it. But, the email notification does not work. I tried the "Send Test Notification" button while you are creating an alert trigger but nothing is sending out in my email.
I tried and added email and also verified it but no notification

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
